# file_get_contents Time PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Pessoal o seguinte eu tenho um file_get_contents no php, mas essa API as vezes sai fora do ar e ela demora muito pra responder, teria como por um tempo limite se passar desse tempo retornar um erro.

Ou alguma ideia de como fazer isso usando curl, eu fiz assim:

```
$url = "..../stations.json";

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        $response=curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);


        $response = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Tem uma resposta no SOen: [Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)

Comment: Obrigado deu certo !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
set_time_limit('tempo-em-segundos');
```